# Setting up JMS Queues in Jboss As 7.1.1

Tags: jms, jboss7.x

I am new to Jboss and JMS. How do we setup JMS Queues in JBoss AS 7.1.1[jboss-as-7.1.1.Final] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in standalone.xml file. You need to add subsystem jboss:domain:messaging
See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Messaging+configuration